# Using GLM with GTK to make simple 3D drawing

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, gtk, glm-math

I am jus trying to draw a 3D Cartesian axis to see if I can get 3D to work.  I am using GTK with Cairo to do the drawing.   Here is my code...

```
glm::vec3 camera_pos(0, 0, -10);
glm::vec3 camera_target(0, 0, 0);
glm::vec3 up(0, 1, 0);

gboolean draw_callback(GtkWidget* widget, cairo_t* cr, gpointer data)
{
    guint width, height;

    width = gtk_widget_get_allocated_width(widget);
    height = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(widget);

    glm::mat4 model = glm::translate(glm::vec3(width / 2.0f, height / 2.0f, 0.0f)) *
            glm::scale(glm::vec3(100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f));
    glm::mat4 camera = glm::lookAt(camera_pos, camera_target, up);
    glm::mat4 perspective = glm::perspective(45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    glm::mat4 transform = perspective * camera * model;

    glm::vec4 xaxis = transform * glm::vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
    glm::vec4 yaxis = transform * glm::vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
    glm::vec4 zaxis = transform * glm::vec4(0, 0, 1, 1);
    glm::vec4 orig = transform * glm::vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);

    cout << orig.x << " " << orig.y << endl;

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1.0, 0, 0);
    cairo_move_to(cr, orig.x, -orig.y);
    cairo_line_to(cr, xaxis.x, -xaxis.y);
    cairo_stroke(cr);

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 1.0, 0);
    cairo_move_to(cr, orig.x, -orig.y);
    cairo_line_to(cr, yaxis.x, -yaxis.y);
    cairo_stroke(cr);

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 1.0);
    cairo_move_to(cr, orig.x, -orig.y);
    cairo_line_to(cr, zaxis.x, -zaxis.y);
    cairo_stroke(cr);

    return FALSE;
}
```

Can someone check the math here because I am getting a lot of negative coordinates.  Nothing appears on my screen when I run this.

Edit:

I just modified my camera vectors like this.

```
gboolean draw_callback(GtkWidget* widget, cairo_t* cr, gpointer data)
{
    guint width, height;

    width = gtk_widget_get_allocated_width(widget);
    height = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(widget);

    glm::vec3 camera_pos(0, 0, 1000);
    glm::vec3 camera_target(width / 2.0f, height / 2.0f, 0);
    glm::vec3 up(0, 1, 0);

    glm::mat4 model = glm::translate(glm::vec3(width / 2.0f, height / 2.0f, 0.0f));// *
            //glm::scale(glm::vec3(100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f));
    glm::mat4 camera = glm::lookAt(camera_pos, camera_target, up);
    glm::mat4 perspective = glm::perspective(45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    glm::mat4 transform = perspective * camera * model;

    glm::vec4 xaxis = transform * glm::vec4(100, 0, 0, 1);
    glm::vec4 yaxis = transform * glm::vec4(0, 100, 0, 1);
    glm::vec4 zaxis = transform * glm::vec4(0, 0, 100, 1);
    glm::vec4 orig = transform * glm::vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);

    cout << xaxis.x << " " << xaxis.y << endl;

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1.0, 0, 0);
    cairo_move_to(cr, orig.x, -orig.y);
    cairo_line_to(cr, xaxis.x, -xaxis.y);
    cairo_stroke(cr);

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 1.0, 0);
    cairo_move_to(cr, orig.x, -orig.y);
    cairo_line_to(cr, yaxis.x, -yaxis.y);
    cairo_stroke(cr);

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 1.0);
    cairo_move_to(cr, orig.x, -orig.y);
    cairo_line_to(cr, zaxis.x, -zaxis.y);
    cairo_stroke(cr);

    return FALSE;
}
```

Now I can see a blue line from the corner of my screen but it is still wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a perspective projection, but you do not carry out the persepctive divide, which will totally screw up your results. `glm::perspective` will create a matrix which maps the viewing frustum with the given angle and apsect ratio along the negative z axis to a [-w,w]^3 "cube" in clip space. After the perspective divide by the `w` coordinate, the viewing frustum will be [-1,1]^3 in normalized device coords. Usually at this stage, the coordinates are further converted into *window space*, where the actual pixels come into play.

In your case, you seem to try to incorporate the window resolution in the `model` transform at the start of the transform chain, which is totally weird if you later apply a standard GL projection matrix.